# App frozen by UIKit after upgrading to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode7

After upgrading my project to Swift 2.0 and using Xcode 7 (GM) I noticed some of my view controllers freeze the app on navigation.

Instruments show me that CPU usage is over 9000% and is used by UIKit and Foundation.

Have you encountered this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be one of those Interface Builder issues.

I've successfully defeated this by removing any text from UITextView in storyboard. And it comes again if I set text property back.

Hopefully, this will help someone to not waste precious time.

Comment: Thank you sharing the fix. Helped me a lot.